# Python Pandas read_html multi_index table?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not sure if it should be called multi index. Here is the page I am trying to get data from:
[Azure product availability by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/?regions=us-east-2,united-kingdom-south&products=all).

There is hierarchy level: class "category-row" --> "service-row" --> "capability-row" .

pandas.read_html give me a flat table, with all values from three classes. Is there a way to get the hierarchy data?

Here is the code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

url = url = 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/?regions=us-east-2,canada-central,canada-east&products=all'
driver.get(url)

tree = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element_by_id("primary-table").get_attribute('outerHTML'), "html5lib")
table = tree.find('table', class_='primary-table')

header_list = table.find('tr', {'class': 'region-headers-row'}).find_all('th')
df = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("primary-table").get_attribute('outerHTML'), header=0)[0].iloc[:, :len(header_list)]``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if it fit your needs, but it is also take the table contents - May provide an expected result.

##### Example

```
...
data=[]
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for r in soup.select('table tr.service-row:has([data-region-slug])'):
    row = [
        r.find_previous('tr', attrs={'class':'category-row'}).th.get_text(strip=True),
        r.th.get_text(strip=True)
    ]
    for c in r.select('td'):
        if c.img:
            row.append(c.img.get('src'))
        else:
            row.append(c.span.text)
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Category']+list(soup.table.stripped_strings))

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                list(
                    zip(
                        ['','']+[c.get('data-colgroup') for c in soup.table.select('th[data-colgroup]')], 
                        df.columns)
                    )
                )
df

mapper = {'//azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-5983f2707de6e50e5020c6059b619845bc5be5434c362ed8e18652d58e15571e/images/page/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/ga.svg':'hook',
          '//azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-5983f2707de6e50e5020c6059b619845bc5be5434c362ed8e18652d58e15571e/images/page/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/planned-active.svg':'planned-active',
          '//azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-5983f2707de6e50e5020c6059b619845bc5be5434c362ed8e18652d58e15571e/images/page/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/preview-active.svg':'preview-active',
          '//azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-5983f2707de6e50e5020c6059b619845bc5be5434c362ed8e18652d58e15571e/images/page/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/preview.svg':'preview'
         }

df.replace(mapper)
```

##### Output

|  |  |  |  | Canada | United States |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Category | Products | Canada Central | Canada East | East US 2 |
| 0 | AI + machine learning | Azure Databricks | hook | hook | hook |
| 1 | AI + machine learning | Azure Bot Services | Not available | Not available | Not available |
| 2 | AI + machine learning | Azure Cognitive Search | hook | hook | hook |
| 3 | AI + machine learning | Microsoft Genomics | Not available | Not available | hook |
| 4 | AI + machine learning | Azure Machine Learning | hook | hook | hook |
| 9613 | Web | Azure Web PubSub | hook | hook | hook |
| 9614 | Web | Azure Fluid Relay | planned-active | Not available | hook |
| 9615 | Virtual desktop infrastructure | Azure Virtual Desktop | Not available | Not available | Not available |
| 9616 | Virtual desktop infrastructure | Azure Lab Services | hook | hook | hook |
| 9617 | Virtual desktop infrastructure | Microsoft Dev Box | preview | Not available | preview |